# OneByOne slider won't work when duplicated on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm making a website that needs the [OneByOne slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/684613) in 4 separate tags.
It works fine in the first tab, but the second, third, and forth it doesn't show anything.

Here is what I have so far: http://codymorton.us/testing/gallery.html

If you look in the source, you can see that I have it in both tabs 1 and 2, but it won't show up on the second one.
I have tested in Firefox, chrome and Opera.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I think you are lucky you got it to work once, the id attribute in HTML must be unique.

```
<div id="slide-wrapper"> // is repeated twice
```

You might have things to change in JavaScript as well accordingly.

2) These 2 files are included twice in your HTML too, you don't need to do so:

```
js/slider/jquery.onebyone.min.js
js/slider/jquery.touchwipe.min.js
```

What I said might be not enough, the JavaScript code needs to be [beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and checked in details to understand how it works, some extra work for your web developer.

**Update:** Contacting the vendor and asking them if it's "possible" to include many of their sliders on one page could be a shortcut, if the answer is negative then you'll have to do some work on your own.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!  I will try all these things tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into your site and have found out that you are setting display:none to 
`#banner .oneByOne_item` and have removed it and the second tabs image is not loaded so it doesnt show up

check the screenshot

[image]